# Word request in Chinese: media transfer, media transformation

Tags: translation, word-choice, word-requests, culture, history

What is the correct Chinese translation of

> English: media transfer, media transformation

> German: Medientransfer, Medientransformation

**Explanation:**

By medium (plural: media) in this context, I mean the material in which and on which the art piece is executed, what is usually included in the description of it after the title, may it be for example: oil on canvas, acrylic on paper, gouache on cartridge, pencil on sketchbook, etc.

In the realm of this question, I go a step further and also allow media which are not necessarily subject of painting/drawing, like: (art) photography, video art, performance, even literature and music, etc.

The meaning of media transfer is the transformation of one and the same subject from one medium to another, may it be the execution of your own painting in several different media with variations in the process but definitely and visibly the same subject, the justification of a pencil "sketch" as a preliminary second medium to fix the volatile ideas before execution in "large shapes", but never a sketch which is not a final art piece and is dropped later on and only serves the purpose of planning, the appropriation or copy of a famous or not so famous art piece, again with variations in the process, due to lack of accurate skills or on purpose, like color transformations, the realization of an art piece after a photography template (艺术照片模板), where I suppose that the photography is art in the first place, eg. a conceived arrangement to be turned into a still life, etc.

I even go a step further and would also call painting after a real life model, painting your dream afterwards, or even a vision or a hallucination, media transfer, where one media in this case is a certain form of subjective or imagined, but fixed, reality.

The notion of media transfer is also closely related to the one of illustration (插图), where the medium of literature is transferred to a picture in a visual medium. For my purpose, I also include musical illustrations, where a piece of music is, in some form, transferred to a picture. It is also related to that of translation (翻译), where different media can be interpreted as different languages.

However, media transfer is *not* the  free, hazardous, coincidental fabulation on a tabula rasa as psychogram without preconceived plan. It can be a psychogram only in as such as by a media transfer, in my sense, this effect can be achieved as well by modifications in the execution from one medium to another.

You might argue that in the later case the artist transfers his instant imagination to a picture. But, I'm not willing to allow this under the term of media transfer. After all, I differentiate between reality, imagined reality and imagination.

Media transfer is also *not* a notion of a doctrine of abstraction which tries to eradicate the subject matter. It can make the subject unrecognizable, however, due to some sort of zooming in or zooming out, due to blurring, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

媒介转换. See for example, adapting a novel to a movie: http://media.people.com.cn/n1/2017/0605/c412723-29317671.html

> 通过转变文学作品中的叙述结构、叙述方式，重塑主要人物形象，实现了影像对文学文本的置换和再造，**媒介的转换**使电影文本具有了不同于文学文本的意义世界。

Comment: Thank you! I'm very happy with this term! Would the term color transfer, translated to Chinese as 颜色转换, also be understandable to you, in the meaning I explained in my question?

Comment: I would say 颜色变换. "颜色转换" has been used as a technical term that means converting between color spaces (RGB, HSL, CMYK, etc.)